# Why isn't obj.style.left = "200px"; working in this code?

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

Why wont `.style.top = "200px";` work in this code? Calling the event within the element using `oclick="this.style.left='200px';"` doesn't work either.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="theDiv">The Div</div>
        <button id="theButton">Do</button>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById("theDiv").style.top = "200px";
    };
</script>
```

Comment: What are the `position`'s set to for each element?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use a `left` or `top` style the element must be `position:absolute`, or `position:relative`, or `position:fixed`