# Javascript if statement if (ball.style.left === '0px') {

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement, equals, semantics

I think the problem is really simple, but I'm not seeing it.
I just want to move the "ball" to the left 132.5px when I click the "dice" and if the ball is 0px left.

**I think the if statement is wrong!! Can someone help me?**

```
var ball = document.getElementById('ball');
var dice = document.getElementById('dice');

function move() {
  if (ball.style.left === '0px') {
    ball.style.left = 132.5 + 'px';
  }

}

dice.onclick = move;
```

Comment: ok, Is your ball element's css attribute  (Position) Absolute ? @Inês Rodrigues

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't obj.style.left = "200px"; working in this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216869/why-isnt-obj-style-left-200px-working-in-this-code)

Comment: yes it is absolute. When I take off the if statement the ball moves when I click the dice. So I think the problem must be    ball.style.left === '0px'

Comment: I think the css is not the problem

Comment: Note that `style` property represents elements' `style` attribute. It's not the computed style of an element. For getting the computed style use `getComputedStyle`  function instead: `window.getComputedStyle(ball).left`. The default value of the `left` property  is `auto`, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is really simple. I came upon it when I was coding a snake in javascript.

When you want to test where the ball is located don't use `ball.style.left` but `ball.offsetLeft`.

In the demo you'll notice `ball.style.left` doesn't return anything while the `offsetLeft` does. Only use `ball.style.left` when you want to change it's position.

http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/3kphhcbu/

This is what you should be doing.

```
if (ball.offsetLeft == 0) {
    ball.style.left = 132.5 + 'px';
  }
```

New demo with an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/3kphhcbu/1/

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try it

Comment: Just remember 0 is now a number and not a string.